# Cant Store Images to public storage (LARAVEL)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Good day.

I have problem why I cant store the image to the public storage.
when i was in localhost the function is working. however when i put in the host it shows the image cant move to the public storage.
what is the problem to that? Thanks I hope you will help me to solved this..

This my controller:

```
$content_image = $request->input('content_assets');
$file_upload = $request->file('content_assets');

if($request->hasFile('content_assets'))
{
    $request->validate([
    'content_assets' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',      
     ]);

    $x = $request->content_assets->storeAs('/public',$content_image);
    dd($x);
}
```

The Output:

**"public/36527000_2029863913704669_3320467206839468032_n.jpg"**

This is the Path:

**C:\xampp\htdocs\Hiflyer\public**

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't save uploaded content directly to your public folder.

Instead, per [**laravels documentation**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/structure#the-storage-directory):

> The `storage/app/public` directory may be used to store user-generated
>   files, such as profile avatars, that should be publicly accessible.
>   You should create a symbolic link at  `public/storage` which points to
>   this directory. You may create the link using the  `php artisan storage:link` command.

Comment: But you're trying to store in `public` when you should be storing in `storage/app/public`

Comment: in my cmd. when i type php artisan storage:link it says The "public/storage" directory already exists.

Comment: Yes, so to save the file you'd just use `$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', 'filename.jpg');`, where `images` is a folder inside `storage/app/public`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Hiflyer\storage\app\public ----------- my path is correct

Comment: @DevGeorge remove the `/` from your code in `storeAs` also, you're passing an object to `storeAs` where the name you want the file to be

Comment: i already fix . the problem was storage link is not updating.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

read this [document about laravel disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk). and then you can store files using:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('/', $file));
```

take note to modify `filesystems.php` file